# Click event is not triggered - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have on my local machine something like this:

```
<form>
...
<input type="submit" name="bouton" id="bouton" style="display:none;" />    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function ()
{
    console.log("test");
    $("#bouton").click();
    //alert("redirection");
}, 150);
</script>
```

When this page is loaded the `click` event is correctly triggered. Now, on my remote server the exact same code does not trigger this event but the `console.log` message works! I tried as suggested by some `SO` post to add `$("#bouton")[0].click();` but it didn't work. How can it be?

Comment: You should encapsulate your JS within the document ready event.

Comment: Why using a timeout here? Try to replicate issue in jsFiddle. In timeout callback, what gives you: `console.log($("#bouton").length);
` ???

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your entire code in this call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code here
});
```

Most likely, the same explanation I did here is valid too: [jquery click event not fired on internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397678/jquery-click-event-not-fired-on-internet-explorer/23397705#23397705)

Please read the entire answer: it contains some information to help you debug your code.

[Jsfiddle of working code](http://jsfiddle.net/sbEy3/).

Comment: Some explanation might be nice as well so OP knows why it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397678/jquery-click-event-not-fired-on-internet-explorer/23397705#23397705

Comment: I tried to wrap my code as you say but iti didn't change anything

Comment: well, your code is working so you should either provide more details or do more debugging. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/sbEy3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("test");
  $("#bouton").click();
   //alert("redirection");
  }, 2000);
});
```

Do check  in http://jsfiddle.net/7M8Gj/

Answer (score 0):

maybe `jQuery` is not loaded yet, try this to ensure

```
var l = document.getElementById("bouton");
l.click();
```